# Angular: Redirect to different pages after login on different conditions

Tags: angular

I have a simple login where you enter email and password and if it is available in the DB, the user can log in. But as logged in user must redirect to specific pages.

for example: If the user login type is 'supplier' user must redirect to a specific page while if not the user must redirect to another page.

This is the service method

```
  login(email, password): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http
      .post(this.uri + '/login', { email, password }, {headers})
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));

  }
```

I would like to redirect to the dashboard, if user is not type 'supplier'

```
     this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

I would like to redirect to the 'supplier' if the user is a supplier

```
    this.router.navigate(['supplier']);
```

The user object from backend is as follows

```
error: false
result:
email: "din@gmail.com"
phone_no: "00000008"
type: "supplier"
user_id: 1
```

For ref, This is the ts file method

```
loginToSystem(): any {
    const email = this.formData().email;
    const password = this.formData().password;

    this.backendService.login(email, password)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.loginData = data;
        console.log(data);
        // console.log('helo');
        console.log(data.result.type);
      });
    console.log(email, password);
  }
```

app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'supplier', component: SupplierComponent}
];
```

appreciate any insight on this matter! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the routes are defined to match the values of the type property returned by your login method you can simply pass the type as the route.

```
loginToSystem(): any {
const email = this.formData().email;
const password = this.formData().password;

this.backendService.login(email, password)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.loginData = data;
    console.log(data);
    // console.log('helo');
    console.log(data.result.type);
    this.router.navigate(['/', data.result.type]);
  });
console.log(email, password);
```

}

Comment: Hey, so even with the change made the page doesn't change

Comment: Can you provide your route definitions

Comment: The routes look ok although it is more normal to put the fallback route last.  The only other thing I can think of is that you need to include '/' in the call to navigate so this.router.navigate(['/', data.result.type])

Answer (score 1):

Should a simple if() not solve your problem?

```
loginToSystem(): any {
    const email = this.formData().email;
    const password = this.formData().password;

    this.backendService.login(email, password)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.loginData = data;
        if(data.result.type === 'supplier') {
          this.router.navigate(['supplier']);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']
        }
      });
    console.log(email, password);
  }
```

this will be a good solution if you only have 2 level_types

Answer (score 0):

so I ended finding the issue. It was an issue of routing where I had to register the other routes as child components of the main component and then following fixing the routes. A simple if condition fixed the issue!